# In Amazon Web Service ec2 why it require 15 min to generate password?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

while using AWS ec2
when i try to launch windows server 2003 instance it give me massage that please wait for 15 min.Actually password generated after 25 min
Why this is happen ?
please help.

Regards,
Tushar

Comment: It gave you a massage? I think I'll give it a try

Comment: Please note, that if you build your own AMI and launch EC2 instances from it, the password is already set based on what was in the AMI image.  So no waiting!!!

Answer (score 3):

There's quite a lot going on behind the scenes when you launch an EC2 instance, and host load, network load and Windows itself can all increase the amount of time it takes between clicking 'Launch' and having the password generated and ready for extraction.

15 minutes is the 'usual' amount of time it can take, but I've had VMs take 20-30 minutes to go from cold to ready-to-use. It's the nature of the environment that your VMs run in - sometimes it just takes a bit longer.